# Append To useState<Array> inside useEffect inside a Promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, use-effect, use-state

In theory the array should be populated continuously and should be reflected in rendering the page but instead it keeps getting overwritten. ending with a list that has only the last added value.
This is a striped down version of what I am trying to obtain.

```js
// Just a function to simulate fetching data from an API
async function getData(id) {
    // Simulate Delay
    await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, id * 1000));
    return `Data ${id}`;
}

function App(props) {
    const [data, setData] = React.useState("Loading...");
    const [arr, setArr] = React.useState([]);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        getData(0).then(setData);
    }, []);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (data && arr.length == 0) {
            for (let i = 1; i < 6; i++) {

                getData(i).then((resolve) => {
                    setArr([resolve, ...arr]);
                });

            }
        } else {
            setArr([]);
        }
    }, [data]);

    return (
        <>
            <h3>{data}</h3>
            <ul>
                {arr.map((item) => (
                    <li key={item}>{item}</li>
                ))}
            </ul>
        </>
    );
}
```

#### Expected

Data 0

- Data 1
- Data 2
- Data 3
- Data 4
- Data 5

#### Instead

Data 0

- Data 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After research I found that you could pass a function to a *setState()* in the form of *(currentStateValue) => {}*.
To prevent the data from being called twice due to the second useEffect being fired twice, create another state *isFetchingMoreData* to check against.

```js
// Just a function to simulate fetching data from an API
async function getData(id) {
    // Simulate Delay
    await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, id * 1000));
    return `Data ${id}`;
}

function App(props) {
    const [data, setData] = React.useState("Loading...");
    const [arr, setArr] = React.useState([]);
    const [isFecthingMoreData, setIsFecthingMoreData] = React.useState(false);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        getData(0).then(setData);
        setIsFecthingMoreData(true);
    }, []);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (isFecthingMoreData) {

            setIsFecthingMoreData(false);

            for (let i = 1; i < 6; i++) 
                getData(i).then((resolve) => {
                setArr((prev )=>[...prev, resolve]);
                });



        } else {
            setArr([]);
        }
    }, [data]);

    return (
        <>
            <h3>{data}</h3>
            <ul>
                {arr.map((item) => (
                    <li key={item}>{item}</li>
                ))}
            </ul>
        </>
    );
}
```